# jsonserializationexception: self referencing loop detected for property

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, json-serialization

I'm using C# asp.net core ef6 linq mssql VS2022

when I build the project I can see this page
[image: jsonserializationexception]

I checked these pages...
[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzbQjagjGUg)
[3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization)

the 2's JsonIgnore was worked but I have problem.

I using ef core power tools [ef core power tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools)
and ef core help me when I update the DB
ef core auto generate the Model...

So JsonIgnore is deleting when I reverse Engineering ( It meens updating DB )

now I'm making viewModel of all the model... and I need to make over 30 ...
could you help me...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully addressed it by utilizing the `AsNoTracking()` method.